# Read property values in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How can I read the properties in a property file inside a Spring boot application?

In a normal Spring application we can do this by adding this in context:

`<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:my.properties"/>`

Then refer the property using:

```
@Value("${my.property.name}")
Private String name;
```

Comment: Besides the answer below, you can use `@ConfigurationProperties` and use the filled up beans in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use @SpringBootApplication and your @Value will pick value from application.properties or yml from resource folder.